# Find JArray/JObject element within JSON file

Tags: c#, arrays, json, linq

Under the **'products'** header, I am trying to find the first value of the **'handle'** variable within the JSON file where the **'price'** element under the **'variants'** header equals **'1.4'**.

I have been struggling to query this via JObject/JArray and wanted to know if there is a way to do it. Here is my JSON file that I am querying from:

```
"products":[{
 "id":124534,
 "handle": "Data1", 
 "variants":[
    {
       "barcode":null,
       "sku":"M11-168-EN-NFNE-0",
       "price":1.5
    },
    {
       "barcode":null,
       "sku":"M11-168-EN-NFNE-0",
       "price":1.5
    }]
},
{
 "id":548562,
 "handle": "Data2", 
 "variants":[
    {
       "barcode":null,
       "sku":"M11-168-EN-NFNE-0",
       "price":1.4,
    }]
}]
```

Any help on this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `variants` is an array, so what if one of its variant's price is 1.4 and another is not? Should it be picked? `products[0].variants[0].price = 1.4`, `products[0].variants[1].price = 1.5`, `products[1].variants[0].price = 1.4`

Comment: Yes, that is the key here, it doesn't matter if other prices don't contain it, as long as it is picked up once then it should get the 'handle' value. 

I do need to mention that the JSON file is subject to change which means it would normally have many more variants and I would get different prices each time. So hard coding the search with product and variants would not work sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose that these are your model classes:

```cs
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Handle { get; set; }
    public Variant[] Variants { get; set; }   
}

public class Variant
{
    public string Barcode { get; set; }
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Then the LINQ query would look like this:

```cs
static string GetTheFirstProductWhereOneOfItsVariantHasAGivenPrice(IEnumerable<Product> products, double expectedPrice)
{
    var product = products
        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Variants.Any(variant => Math.Abs(variant.Price - expectedPrice) < 0.05));
    return product?.Handle ?? "Not Found";
}
```

- It tries to find the first Product (if any) << `products.FirstOrDefault`
- where there is a variant with a given price (inside the error margin) << `Variants.Any`
- If there is one then it returns with its `Handle` property otherwise with `Not Found`

The usage would look like this:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    const double expectedPrice = 1.4;
    string secondProductWithTheGivenPrice =
        "[{\r\n \"id\":124534,\r\n \"handle\": \"Data1\", \r\n \"variants\":[\r\n    {\r\n       \"barcode\":null,\r\n       \"sku\":\"M11-168-EN-NFNE-0\",\r\n       \"price\":1.5\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n       \"barcode\":null,\r\n       \"sku\":\"M11-168-EN-NFNE-0\",\r\n       \"price\":1.5\r\n    }]\r\n},\r\n{\r\n \"id\":548562,\r\n \"handle\": \"Data2\", \r\n \"variants\":[\r\n    {\r\n       \"barcode\":null,\r\n       \"sku\":\"M11-168-EN-NFNE-0\",\r\n       \"price\":1.4,\r\n    }]\r\n}]";

    var products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product[]>(secondProductWithTheGivenPrice);
    Console.WriteLine(GetTheFirstProductWhereOneOfItsVariantHasAGivenPrice(products, expectedPrice));

    string firstProductWithTheGivenPrice =
        "[{\r\n \"id\":124534,\r\n \"handle\": \"Data1\", \r\n \"variants\":[\r\n    {\r\n       \"barcode\":null,\r\n       \"sku\":\"M11-168-EN-NFNE-0\",\r\n       \"price\":1.5\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n       \"barcode\":null,\r\n       \"sku\":\"M11-168-EN-NFNE-0\",\r\n       \"price\":1.4\r\n    }]\r\n},\r\n{\r\n \"id\":548562,\r\n \"handle\": \"Data2\", \r\n \"variants\":[\r\n    {\r\n       \"barcode\":null,\r\n       \"sku\":\"M11-168-EN-NFNE-0\",\r\n       \"price\":1.4,\r\n    }]\r\n}]";

    products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product[]>(firstProductWithTheGivenPrice);
    Console.WriteLine(GetTheFirstProductWhereOneOfItsVariantHasAGivenPrice(products, expectedPrice));

    string withoutGivenPrice =
        "[{\r\n \"id\":124534,\r\n \"handle\": \"Data1\", \r\n \"variants\":[\r\n    {\r\n       \"barcode\":null,\r\n       \"sku\":\"M11-168-EN-NFNE-0\",\r\n       \"price\":1.5\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n       \"barcode\":null,\r\n       \"sku\":\"M11-168-EN-NFNE-0\",\r\n       \"price\":1.6\r\n    }]\r\n},\r\n{\r\n \"id\":548562,\r\n \"handle\": \"Data2\", \r\n \"variants\":[\r\n    {\r\n       \"barcode\":null,\r\n       \"sku\":\"M11-168-EN-NFNE-0\",\r\n       \"price\":1.3,\r\n    }]\r\n}]";

    products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product[]>(withoutGivenPrice);
    Console.WriteLine(GetTheFirstProductWhereOneOfItsVariantHasAGivenPrice(products, expectedPrice));

}
```

The output would look like this:

```
Data2
Data1
Not Found
```

Comment: Thanks you for the explanation, the LINQ query is what I was seeking here and it works in my solution. Have a blessed day my friend!